# Upload an image and change the background

Tags: css, reactjs, input, file-upload

I'm trying to make the background change whenever the user is uploading an image, the background is set on default however, I found that I have to use `<input />` but then I got stuck

this my work so far !

```
const [backgroundShown, setBackgroundShown] = useState(false);
```

---

```
const changeBackground = () => {

        setBackgroundShown(!backgroundShown);
      };
```

---

```
        {file && (
                <img
                    className="writeImg"
                    src={URL.createObjectURL(file)}
                />
            )
        }
        <form className="writeForm" onSubmit={handlerSubmit}>
            <div className="writeFormGroup">
                <label htmlFor="fileInput">
                    <img 
                    type={backgroundShown ? "img" : "file"}
                    className="writeIcon"
                    src="/Images/Upload-Vector.png"
                    ></img>
                </label>
                <div>
                <input 
                onClick={changeBackground}
                type={backgroundShown ? "file" : "img"}
                accept="image/*"
                id="fileInput" 
                style={{ display: "none" }} 
                onChange={e => setFile(e.target.files[0])}>
                </input>
                </div>
```

Comment: Just remove that backgroundShown logic altogether. https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-cache-seq2ss?file=/src/App.tsx your code works fine. Cool btw! I didn't know about this kind of client-only upload.

Comment: @Yuji'Tomita'Tomita but if I remove this backgroundShown the background will still it will not disappear, what I want is the background to be shown by default but when the user upload an image the background should be disappeared and replaced by the image that the user uploaded

Comment: I don't really get it -- see code sandbox. Upload an image, then upload another. Anyway, it all seems to work well.

Comment: @Yuji'Tomita'Tomita thank you for replying me, but you didn't understand me, the code is uploading the images great, but I want it whenever the user is uploading an image the "upload" button DISAPPEARED and REPLACED by the image that the user uploaded, hope you understood me now.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to remove the button when the user "uploads".

If so, just conditionally render it when the user *hasn't* uploaded.

```
  {file && (
                <img
                    className="writeImg"
                    src={URL.createObjectURL(file)}
                />
            )
        }
   {!file && 
        <form className="writeForm" onSubmit={handlerSubmit}>
            <div className="writeFormGroup">
                <label htmlFor="fileInput">
                    <img 
                    type={backgroundShown ? "img" : "file"}
                    className="writeIcon"
                    src="/Images/Upload-Vector.png"
                    ></img>
                </label>
                <div>
                <input 
                onClick={changeBackground}
                type={backgroundShown ? "file" : "img"}
                accept="image/*"
                id="fileInput" 
                style={{ display: "none" }} 
                onChange={e => setFile(e.target.files[0])}>
                </input>
                </div>
    }
```